# Is there any precision issues for parallelization of pandas?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-multiprocessing

I'm trying to parallelize the processing of big dataframe using **Pool** of **multiprocessing** module, in 64-bit architecture system. I splitted a dataframe using np.array_split(), called apply(), and compared resulting dataframes - one from batch and the other from parallel processing. 
And what I've found is that there are some difference between those two data frames.

I tested for DataFrame.mean(), DataFrame.median(), DataFrame.std(), and other lambda functions but only for DataFrame.std(), I could find the small difference.

The scale of differences about 10^-13. Is there any known issues about the floating-point precision when Pool of multiprocessing module is used for DataFrame.std()?

Comment: The problem should not be a tied to multi-processing, but to the way you split the dataframe and do your computations on the partial dataframes. If you do **exactly** the same operations in an iterative or parallel way, you should get the same results. Cannot say more without a [mcve]...

Comment: @SergeBallesta Sorry for not providing actual code but the code and corresponding data are confidential ones (so I cannot copy and edit directly). I'll try to make a reproducible example instead. But in the way of split, there is no problem because there are no such differences in the results of other operations like mean or median, etc on the splitted ones.